# Popup on :hover that works with IE7?

Tags: internet-explorer-7, hover, yui, hidden

http://jsfiddle.net/9LuS2/

This code seems to work in modern browsers + IE8. But in IE7 (open up IE, hit F12 and do IE7 mode) the fiddle doesn't work at all, and in the actual page I am working on it doesn't work, but then if you click it, it appears, but then won't go away.

What is the best way to do a hover event with DIVs that will work going back to IE7.

Do I need to use JS?

If so can someone suggest either pure JS or YUI lib as I cannot use jquery for this project.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/ is your friend. It fixes many older ie browser. It is Java script, but you don't have to worry about writing any java script, it is all done. Just add link to page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, old IEs don't like `.test:hover .test_hidden` (selectors for inner elements of `:hover`).

If JS is an option, you can use the [hover event](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/api/modules/event-hover.html) in YUI:

```
​YUI().use('node', 'event-hover', function (Y) {
    var outer = Y.one('.test');
    var inner = Y.one('.test_inner');

    function showInnerDiv() {
        inner.removeClass('test_inner_hidden');
    }
    function hideInnerDiv() {
        inner.addClass('test_inner_hidden');
    }

    outer.on('hover', showInnerDiv, hideInnerDiv);
});​​​​​​
```